# Where does wireshark get its microsecond timers from

Tags: windows, timer, timing, performancecounter, wireshark

Wireshark times events down to microseconds and appears to do so with great accuracy. My question is where in the world do those timers come from when running under windows? If the answer is "it uses thus and such library" then my question is "well, where does that library get its timers under windows"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QueryPerformanceCounter
```

That's function for timing with highest precision on windows I know

EDIT:
Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904(VS.85).aspx